# How can i convert a set of ascii characters to string

Tags: javascript, string, ascii

I have a set of ascii characters :

```
68,101,97,108
```

I want to convert this to a string :

```
Deal
```

in java script

Im currently doing something like :

```
var value = "68,101,97,108";
var convertedValue = "";
for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
{
     convertedValue += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(value[i], 2));
}
```

This returns a blank string

Comment: Not exactly related, but [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) expects an Unicode value as arguments, not ASCII code.

Comment: @Teemu. Yes, it expects a Unicode/UTF-16 code-unit, one or two of which encode a codepoint. @lokoko Unicode is a superset of ASCII and maps the same integers (codepoints) to the same characters. UTF-16 encodes all of those in one code-unit. So, `String.fromCharCode()` has the effect that you think it does without actually doing what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get array `valueArray`  from `value` then you iterate on it

```js
var value = "68,101,97,108";
var convertedValue = "";
valueArray = value.split(",")
for (var i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++)
{
     convertedValue += String.fromCharCode(valueArray[i]);
}

alert(convertedValue);
```